# Manual steps to modify the IP address of an ESXI host in the Centos 7 dns records.This dns VM is running on the same host

Tags: server, dns, centos

Need complete steps to manually modify the IP address of an ESXI host in the Centos 7 dns server records.This dns VM is running on the same host.

Edit the Zone File, using sudo nano /var/named/chroot/var/named/master/example.com.fqdn, and updated the new IP address. reverse DNS (PTR) record for your ESXi host after changing its IP address, sudo systemctl reload named-failed
the below command giving service status as failed.
systemctl status named.service

Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
please check this and let me know how to start the named.service unable tp start the service.